# Javascript SideBar stays open with page change

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a side bar that opens with a simple javascript toggle that I want to keep open during page change if user has sidebar toggled open.

When clicking openMenu button it runs toggle function.

HTML:

```
<h2 onclick="toggleSidebar()"><a href="#">Table of
                    Contents</a></h2>

<nav id="sidenav">
    <div id="top-sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">Table of Contents
            &ThickSpace;&times;</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>
            <a href="chapter/1.html">Chapter 1
                <p>Down the Rabbit-Hole</p>
            </a>

        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").classList.toggle("active");
    document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("sideNavActive");
    document.getElementById("buttonHomepage").classList.toggle("sideNavTopBar");
    document.getElementById("prevChapter").classList.toggle("sideNavActive");

}
```

Comment: can you give me few more clarity on the request? you mean you want to open using local storage instead of js function?

Comment: @KannanG I am wanting the sidebar to stay open on page change if the user has it opened. Otherwise stay closed.

Comment: thanks, let me try and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the method,

In your body or document ready follow like below to achieve,

HTML

```
<body onload=loadMenu()>
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  loadMenu()
})
```

or - if you have jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     loadMenu();
});
```

Script

```
function loadMenu() {
    if(getLocalStorage("openMenu") == "true") {
        toggleSidebar() 
    }
}

function toggleSidebar() {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").classList.toggle("active");
    document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("sideNavActive");
    document.getElementById("buttonHomepage").classList.toggle("sideNavTopBar");
    document.getElementById("prevChapter").classList.toggle("sideNavActive");
/*for toggle the menu on localstorage*/
    (getLocalStorage("openMenu") == "true" ? setLocalStorage("openMenu", false) : setLocalStorage("openMenu", true)); //wil toggle and trigger menu when modal opened
}

function setLocalStorage(key, value) {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    { 
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);  
    }
}

function getLocalStorage(key) {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
       return window.localStorage.getItem(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use session based cookie for same purpose, instead of using localstorage.

Comment: Yes but the request is to handle localstorage that's why

Comment: @KannanG Thanks very much for the help! Works well, are we able to make it so the menu stays open across multiple page changes ? At the moment it will only keep it's state across one change.

Comment: Yes if we add it, ex.. if you open the menu any number of page if yo go page wil be open state as long as if yo close menu it wil remain close. Yo need any other functionality? If so tel me